# Linear Algebra Vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Can you guys take a look at this?

Let $\mathcal P_3(\mathbb R)$ be  the  set  of  polynomials  of  degree smaller or equal to $3$ with real  coefficients.  Show  that

$$\{f\in \mathcal P_3(\mathbb R)\mid f(2)=0\},$$

is a vector space with the standard operations.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: what have you tried ? where are you stuck ? [Mathjax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What is P3be supposed to be?

Comment: Well how do you show that a space is a subspace?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $f, g, h \in P_3$. Then, $P_3$ is a vector space if the following axioms are satisfied:

$$f+(g+h) =(f+g) +h $$
$$f+g=g+f$$
$$\exists 0\in P_3 : f+0=f$$
$$\exists 1\in \Bbb R : 1f=f$$
$$\forall f \in P_3, \exists  (-f)\in P_3 : f+(-f)=0$$
$$(ab)f=a(bf)\forall a, b\in \Bbb R$$
$$a(f+g) =af+ag$$
$$(a+b) f=af+bf$$

Most of them are straightforward to show.